# Where can I find the Genesis transaction?

Tags: tangle

Is there any Tangle explorer where I can find the Genesis transaction and browse from there through the Tangle? In Bitcoin I already found the [Genesis Block](https://blockchain.info/block-index/14849).

Answer (score 1):

The Genesis transaction is the transaction with all its trits set to 0. You should be able to find it via its hash - 999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999 - but for going through Tangle it's better to start from the tips.

Comment: Unfortunately no Tangle Explorer I tried can find this hash...

Comment: Same here. Anything new about this topic?